# Why the notation for complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

Why do we use the a + bi notation for complex numbers? We don't use that notation for any other two dimensional quantity do we? If not, why use it exclusively for complex numbers?

Comment: People do use it for normal numbers, for example 5 is 5+0i which is just written as 5

Comment: We use the notation $a \hat i + b\hat j$ for vectors.  We use $a + b i  + c j + d k$ for quaternions.  The notation is not alien to other 2-dimensional objects.

Comment: This also fits with the notation used for algebraic field extensions $\mathbb F(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just notation -- $a+bi$ literally means to take the two real numbers, multiply one of them by $i$ and add the result to the other real number. These two operations are the *same* multiplication and addition operations that work for complex numbers in general, so once we know how to write a real number and have given a name to the constant $i$, *no additional definitions* are necessary to make sense of the $a+bi$ notation.

This fortunate situation is not present for many other "two-dimensional quantities", and therefore they need some ad-hoc notation for combining their two components into a single quantity.  But there is no need to go to such detours for complex numbers.

---

Note, however, that in particular in engineering texts it seems to be somewhat common to write 2-dimensional vectors from $\mathbb R^2$ not as $(a,b)$ but as $a\hat\imath+b\hat\jmath$ with $\hat\imath$ and $\hat\jmath$ being conventional names for basis vectors -- which is more or less the same principle as for $a+bi$.

Answer (score 2):

A complex number is by definition a "number" composed by a real part and an imaginary part.

$$z = a + ib$$

or also

$$z = x + iy$$

or whatever you want.

The notation is comfortable because it makes you to see immediately what the real and imaginary parts be.

$$a = \text{real part}$$

$$b = \text{imaginary part}$$

It's simply... effective! Immediate.

P.s. What other two dimensional quantities?

Answer (score 0):

A complex number is not a two dimension thing, it is a certain type of number. You can find a isomorphism between the complex numbers and the points on the Cartesian plane, i.e. every complex number has a representation on the Argand plane but that doesn't mean its two dimensional. For two dimensional things we often use the notation $(x,y)$. Here $x$ and $y$ are numbers and depending on the situation could be various types of numbers, e.g. natural numbers if we are naming streets/avenues in a city.